# Creating Android AAR file from open source and add it to my own project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar, aar

Hey all I am having a difficult time figuring out why the export of an .aar file does not seem to be working when I add it to my own project.

I am using the [Expanable-tab](https://github.com/nambicompany/expandable-fab) project and it compiles the library it has to an .aap file via the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

ext.versionMajor = 1
ext.versionMinor = 2
ext.versionPatch = 1

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode versionMajor * 100000 + versionMinor * 100 + versionPatch * 1
        versionName "$versionMajor.$versionMinor.$versionPatch"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "expandable-fab")

        // Changes the name of generated AAR artifacts to be more descriptive
        libraryVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                if (outputFileName.endsWith('.aar')) {
                    outputFileName = "${archivesBaseName}-${versionName}.aar"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
}

apply from: 'generate-docs-and-update-website.gradle'
apply from: 'publish-artifacts-to-maven-repo.gradle'
```

When I rebuild the project I navigate to the `expandable-fab-master\library\build\outputs\aar` directory where `expandable-fab-1.2.1.aar` file has been produced.

[image]

I then copy the .aap file to my libs folder in my own project:

[image]

Then I proceed to add this to the build.gradle:

[image]

All of this compile when selecting the rebuild option - no errors.

However, when it gets to the point in my app that uses the expandable-fab code it crashes with this as the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp, PID: 19960
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36 in com.myapp:layout/_fragvideoplay1: Binary XML file line #36 in com.myapp:layout/_fragvideoplay1: Error inflating class com.nambimobile.widgets.efab.ExpandableFabLayout
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36 in com.myapp:layout/_fragvideoplay1: Error inflating class com.nambimobile.widgets.efab.ExpandableFabLayout
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

And the code its referencing (videoPlay.java:99):

[image]

If I comment out the `implementation files('libs/expandable-fab-1.2.1.aar')` and uncomment the original `implementation 'com.nambimobile.widgets:expandable-fab:1.2.1'` and then run the app it works as it should...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of how you're using the aar file as a gradle dependency. Since you already have

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
```

You don't have to do

```
implementation("libs/library_name")
```

instead do this:

```
implementation(name: "library_name", ext: "aar")
```

I hope this helps.